# MessageBox with a comboBox inside and return the value of the comboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, return-value, messagebox

I would like to show a messageBox with a comboBox display on the messageBox and returning the comboBox result. But I dun noe how to add a comboBox inisde the messageBox. I'm using visual studio and the programming language is vb.net. Anyone can help?
The messageBox I want is MessageBox.Show(), Not MsgBox().
Thx for your help~~

Comment: `MsgBox` is just a VB wrapper for `MessageBox`.  To add a combo, you either need to write your own dialog or perhaps use a `TaskDialog`.

Comment: MessageBox.Show and MsgBox are the same thing.

Comment: @Plutonix how to write own dialog?

Comment: You already know how: design a form and show it using `.ShowDialog()`

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom Form instead with `.ShowDialog()` method. You may have to somehow override the `DialogResult` Enumeration though I'd think just passing back whatever you need may be simpler.

Update:
If the combobox provides integer values, you could do something like this if you set DialogResult to that integer in your custom form. FYI `ShowMsg` is my overloaded function that will display my custom form based on the arguments sent.

```
Dim Result As DialogResult = _
    ShowMsg("Select from the combobox", "Select an integer", ShowMsgButtons.OK, ShowMsgImage.Exclmation, ShowMsgDefaultButton.Button1)
Select Case Result
    Case 10
        'what happens when they select 10 from the combobox
    Case 20
        'what happens when they select 20 from the combobox
    Case 30
        'what happens when they select 30 from the combobox
End Select
```

Comment: So i need to use a Form and add some button with the different DialogResult? For example btnOk - DialogResult = OK, btnCancel - DialogResult = Cancel. Then I called the form with `If frmComboBox.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
`

Comment: but how I return the value of the comboBox of the Form I called?

Comment: @JayChuah Expose it as a property

Comment: If the values from the combobox are not `Integers`, then a Property as Plutonix just said would be easiest. `DialogResult` is just an `Integer` so it would be possible to pass back integer values from the comboBox if you wanted.

Comment: @JayChuah why dont you give it a shot and then post a question if you get stuck.  You will never learn anything copying and pasting from Stackoverflow

Comment: @Plutonix Ok~ Thanks for your advice.

Comment: There is also 36,200 Q+As here on that very topic

Comment: @topshot I wouldn't suggest replacing the DialogResult with your own integer value.  That would be very confusing, especially if the user cancels the form.

Comment: @LarsTech I agree in general. Property would be simpler to keep track of. Just offering the alternative. I don't pass back oddball integers, but I also don't allow the user to cancel my custom form if certain buttons are shown (exactly how the built-in messagebox operates).